# ASP.NET MVP Injecting Service Dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mvp

I have an ASP.NET page that implements my view and creates the presenter in the page constuctor.  [Phil Haack's post providing was used as the starting point](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/08/09/ASP.NETSupervisingControllerModelViewPresenterFromSchematicToUnitTestsToCode.aspx), and I'll just the examples from the post to illustrate the question.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page, IPostEditView {

    PostEditController controller;
    public _Default()
    {
         this.controller = new PostEditController(this, new BlogDataService());
    }
}
```

What is the best approach to inject the instance of the BlogDataService?  The examples I have found use properties in the Page class for the dependency marked with an attribute which the injection framework resolves.

However, I prefer using the constructor approach for testing purposes.

Does anyone have input or perhaps links to good implementations of the above.  I would prefer Ninject, but StructureMap or Windsor would be fine as long as its fluent.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [Microsoft ServiceLocator](http://www.codeplex.com/CommonServiceLocator), you can apply the [service locator design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707905.aspx) and ask the container for the service.

In your case it would look something like this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page, IPostEditView {

    PostEditController controller;
    public _Default()
    {
         var service = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IBlogDataService>();
         this.controller = new PostEditController(this, service);
    }
}
```

ServiceLocator has implementations for Castle Windsor and StructureMap.  Not sure about Ninject, but it's trivial to create a ServiceLocator adapter for a new IoC.

Comment: Using this approach, the view now knows about the IBlogDataService which should only have been known to the presenter. Is there a way to construct the presenter using a DI container passing in the current view object and the configured IBlogDataService instance?

Comment: Using a service locator is considered an anti-pattern for IoC. There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

In our homegrown MVP-framework we had a typed base-class that all Pages inherited from. The type needed to be of type Presenter (our base presenter class)

In the base-class we then initialized the controller using the IoC-container.

Sample code:

```
public class EditPage : BasePage<EditController> {
}

public class EditController : Presenter {
 public EditController(IService service) { }
}

public class BasePage<T> : Page where T: Presenter
{
 T Presenter { get; set; }
 public BasePage() { 
  Presenter = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>(); //StructureMap
 }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a general purpose method for doing constructor injection on webforms.  I assume it may be possible via a PageFactory implementation, but since most on the edge right now are moving to MVC rather than webforms, that may not happen.

However, [autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) (a DI container I like a lot) has an [integration module for ASP.NET WebForms](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AspNetIntegration) that does property injection without attributes - your code would look like this :

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page, IPostEditView {

    public IBlogDataService DataService{get;set;}
    public _Default()
    {
    }
}
```

I know this doesn't specifically solve your desire to use constructor injection, but this is the closest I know of.

Comment: Will the container guarantee the property is set prior to the constructor code being called?  Feels a little chicken and the egg to me.

Comment: No, the property will be set after the constructor is called.  One of the pains of webforms, I'm afraid.

Comment: I ended up using autofac instead of ServiceLocator, but in the style Neil has above.  Thanks for this.